# Link to a data category on another page?

Tags: html, categories

I was wondering if it's possible to hyperlink to a data category on another page at all?

Something link this below is what I have coded on the page.

```
<div class="g-filters-list">
<div class="g-filters-item active" data-category="*">All</div>
<div class="g-filters-item" data-category="video-2">Video</div>
<div class="g-filters-item" data-category="illustration">Illustration</div>
<div class="g-filters-item" data-category="custom">Custom</div>
<div class="g-filters-item" data-category="photography">Photography</div>
<div class="g-filters-item" data-category="web-design-2">Web design</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using some sort of client-side JavaScript framework here?

Comment: Your question is unclear but (from what I understand from it, that I may well be mistaken), this looks like a case in which you could use the `id` attribute, and link to the page using the hash symbol (`#`). E.g.: to go to the section `video-2` in page.html, you'd create a link like `page.html#video-2`